# Is is ok to run multiple PHP Websockets using 1 machine?

Tags: debian

I am using Debian LAMP Server and I need to run PHP Websockets with very simple coding.

Will need at least five different WebSockets running with same IP different ports but as you know this things use a 1s looping.

I ran one using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, another at <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and another one at <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>; and they all seem to work ok.

Is it Ok to use one machine to do this, or is that not recommendable at all?

I am expecting around 100 connections on each one.

Comment: This seems like an opinion Q to me. Can you make this a little bit more objective instead of subjective? Add info about the hardware would be a good place to start, but ultimately I'm afraid this will still be an opinion Q which is off-topic on the SE sites.

Comment: I dont know the hardware specs yet. I am testing it locally.